# How good is the default encryption method provided by the Encrypt module?

Tags: webforms, security

I want to encrypt certain field values from webform submissions and will use webform_encrypt module to achieve this. This is dependant on encrypt module.

I am interested to know how satisfactory are the default encryption methods which are included with Encrypt module?

For encryption method settings, I am using the default settings as below

Mcrypt AES (CBC Mode)
Uses PHP's Mcrypt extension and AES in CBC mode. The key MUST be 16, 24, or 32 bytes.

I am also using the Base64 decode method with the key stored in a file outside the web root.

The generated key looks like this (I have changed most of the characters)

EKEIoRp+R8de2bP4JPj7Ut==

I don't know much about this stuff and I am unsure how strong this key is? It has 24 characters. Is it therefore a 24bit key?

Are any simple methods available to use a much longer key?

Comment: Dang. I mis-spelt encrypt tag. Does anybody have permission to correct this?

Comment: Yup, I have fixed it :)

Comment: 1byte = 8bits, your key is 24bytes * 8bits = 192bits (AES-192). The other AES- flavours (128 and 256) use the same maths, different key length (16 and 32 bytes respectively). Have a look at [this post about AES-256](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85773/is-aes-256-secure-enough-for-putting-backups-to-aws-or-dropbox) to get an idea of how secure it's considered

Comment: That's not quite right. This is base64 so you don't get the full 8 bits of entropy for each character of the encoded version, and the padding at the end doesn't count towards entropy either. If you decode the base64 (e.g. using base64 -d | wc -c) it comes out as 16 bytes or 128 bits.

Comment: So if doubled the key length to something like iEKEIoRp+R8de2bP4JPj7Ut==EKEIoRp+R8de2bP4JPj7Ut== Would I have a 256 bi key?